# Crystal reports formula using variables

Tags: crystal-reports

I need a formula like this:

```
if {@TarSale_TimeWise}= 0 or isnull({@TarSale_TimeWise}) then '-' 
else
totext(round(({@ActSale_TimeWise}-{@TarSale_TimeWise})/{@TarSale_TimeWise}*100,1),1)
```

Here the formula for `{@TarSale_TimeWise}` is

```
round({CatTimeWise.tarSale},1)
```

Similarly the formula for `{@ActSale_TimeWise}` is

```
round({CatTimeWise.ActSale},1)
```

I need to take rounding as 1 for both the fields and then I need to do the calculation for var sale with values round as 1 for both the formulas.

Now instead of creating this below 2 formulas and using those in 3rd formula I want to create only one formula using variables.
How can I modify above formulas as 1 formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create only one formula and write below code:

```
Local Numbervar a1:=round({CatTimeWise.tarSale},1)  ;
Local NumberVar a2:=round({CatTimeWise.ActSale},1) ;

if a1= 0 or isnull(a1) then '-' 
else
totext(round((a2-a1)/a1*100,1),1)
```

Comment: Hi Siva i am getting an error like this .A field is required here .It is highlighting isnull(a1) .

Comment: ok `isnull` accepts only field then for null use something like `a1=""` and try

Comment: Hi Siva i did like this.Is it correct ? if {CatTimeWise.tarSale}=0 or isnull({CatTimeWise.tarSale}) then '-' else ..................So instead of taking a1 i took direct field.Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
If Isnull({CatTimeWise.tarSale}) Or {CatTimeWise.tarSale}=0 Then 
  '-' 
Else
  ToText( Round( (({CatTimeWise.ActSale} - {CatTimeWise.tarSale}) / {CatTimeWise.tarSale}*100), 1), 1 )
```